# Adding an image in the image editor through python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, uv-image-editor

I was trying to automate the process of adding an image in the image editor through python. Well i kind of succeeded, but only in changing the resolution and not the color/alpha values. I seem to be lost at this part, i want the alpha value of the image to be 0 and i cant seem to find a way to automate that through python.

[image]

## How can i change the alpha value of the image im adding through python ?

Comment: Please post code as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Color is a parameter of `bpy.ops.image.new()`:

```
bpy.ops.image.new(name="Untitled", width=1024, height=1024, color=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), alpha=True, generated_type='BLANK', float=False, gen_context='NONE', use_stereo_3d=False)
```

[bpy.ops.image.new in API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.ops.image.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20image%20new#bpy.ops.image.new)